# SAS macro doesn't work, but no errors or warnings

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I am constructing ROC curve in SAS University with 100 observations where State is state of nature - positive or negative test, and OD is optical density. Data set is called datain.

```
data datain;
length State $ 1;
input State $ OD @@;
datalines;
P 0.745 N 0.790 P 1.440 P 0.790 (and so on...);
run;
%let lowlim=0.50;
%let uplim=1.50;
%macro roc(datain, lowlim, uplim, ninc=20);
options mtrace mprint;
data roc;
set &datain;
lowlim=&lowlim; uplim=&uplim; ninc=&ninc;
do i=1 to ninc+1;
cutoff=lowlim+(i-1)*((uplim-lowlim)/ninc);
if OD > cutoff then test="R"; else test="N";
output;
end;
drop i;
run;
proc print;
run;
%mend;
```

When I run macro and proc print, there are no errors or warning. In LOG says:

```
OPTIONS NONOTES NOSTIMER NOSOURCE NOSYNTAXCHECK;
ODS HTML CLOSE;
&GRAPHTERM; ;*';*";*/;RUN;QUIT;
QUIT;RUN;
ODS HTML5 (ID=WEB) CLOSE;
ODS RTF (ID=WEB) CLOSE;
ODS PDF (ID=WEB) CLOSE;
FILENAME _GSFNAME;
DATA _NULL_;
RUN;
OPTIONS VALIDMEMNAME=COMPAT;
OPTIONS NOTES STIMER SOURCE SYNTAXCHECK;
```

Any idea why this isn't working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried actually calling your macro?

```
%roc(datain,&lowlim,&uplim,ninc=20);
```

Comment: Agree, but looks like the call should be: `%roc(datain, &lowlim, &uplim, ninc=20)`

Comment: Yes, sorry that was it. I'm very new at this. How can I transform this code
proc gplot data=roc;
plot tp_rate*fp_rate=cutoff;
run;
using sgplot?

Comment: Thanks Quentin - updated.  Lucija - not sure what you are asking, I suggest making a new question with a clear explanation of what you are trying to achieve, along with what you have tried..